# How to create a TextArea in Android

Tags: android

How do I display a TextArea for my android project? From xml, the only choice is TextField, multi lined. But thats editable. I need a TextArea which is only for displaying messages/text can't be edit/input by the user.

Comment: Try to use `EditText` view - [EditText documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html).

Comment: You need something in style like EditText field or TextView?

Comment: Use Text-view for this purpose it is the best suitable for your case.

Comment: the problem of textview i find it shows what ever is it of my background which i had images making reading difficult

Comment: use background color to TextView, it solves your problem.

Comment: Try this code, will help you sure. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47813929/3448003

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its really simple, write this code in XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/fname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="First Name"
/>
```

Answer (score 53):

Try this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top"/>
```

Comment: Common language is English.

Answer (score 18):

Use `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dip">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: How do i insert multi lined description into that?

Answer (score 17):

If you do not want to allow user to enter text `TextView` is the best option here. Any how you can also add `EditText` for this purpose. here is a sample code for that.

This would automatically show scrollbar if there is more text than the specified lines.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="8"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:minLines="6"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

**Edit:** Adding attributes below to `textView` would make it a `textArea` that would not be editable.

```
android:lines="8"
android:maxLines="10"
android:minLines="6" // optional
```

Answer (score 8):

```
       <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:hint="Write your comment.."
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textSize="15sp">
            <requestFocus />
       </EditText>
```

Comment: Thank you bro. It helped me very much. But may i know why you used android:ems="10" and <requestFocus/>

Answer (score 7):

Use `TextView` inside a `ScrollView` to display messages with any no.of lines. User can't edit the text in this view as in `EditText`.

I think this is good for your requirement. Try it once.

You can change the default color and text size in XML file only if you want to fix them as below:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:textSize="25px"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
```

or if you want to change dynamically whenever you want use as below:

```
TextView textarea = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);  // tv is id in XML file for TextView
textarea.setTextSize(20);
textarea.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0xff, 0, 0));
textarea.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.ITALIC);
```

Comment: let me try that see how it goes

Comment: Yes it is very good for my requirement. Now how do i changes its font/size/color ? Default text seem to be gray faded-ish, which visibility is poor.

Comment: in where should i put textarea.setTextSize(20); ,it doesnt look like it is for xml.

Comment: No i am not, and i am using eclipse.

Comment: Yes, i am using textview now instead of edittext. Can you check my other questions?

Comment: @KennethLhv did you mean other questions asked by you ?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717385/android-how-to-link-xml-with-button

Answer (score 6):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/comments_textbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="comments"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:longClickable="false" />
```

use it to create multi line text box like textArea in Html

Answer (score 1):

Defining an Android Mulitline EditText Field is done via the inputType=”textMultiline”. Unfortunately the text looks strangely aligned. To solve that also use the gravity=”left|top” attribute.

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:ems="10"
   android:gravity="left|top"
   android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

   <requestFocus />
```

check this [vogella blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/11/07/how-to-define-a-android-multiline-edittext/)

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers are good but not complete. Use this.

```
 <EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
      android:background="@drawable/text_area_background"
      android:gravity="start|top"
      android:hint="@string/write_your_comments"
      android:imeOptions="actionDone"
      android:importantForAutofill="no"
      android:inputType="textMultiLine"
      android:padding="12dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this short answer might help someone who is looking to do.
add this simple code in your code

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:editable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/question_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:typeface="normal" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_layout"
    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="top"/>
```

Create a Drawable Resource file called border_layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/custom_grey" />
    </shape>
```

custom grey color under values->colors.xml

```
    <color name="custom_grey">#494646</color>
```