# ClassNotFoundException with a TextArea

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, textarea, classnotfoundexception

I'm having an error i don't understand :
I have got a fragment, here is the code and the xml

```
public class OrigineFragment extends Fragment {

private Mission mission;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_origine, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextArea android:id="@+id/date_appel_origine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/date_appel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have got a ClassNotFoundException when inflating the TextArea, and have no clue why it behave like that, but i guess it has something to do with fragment maybe ?

`E/AndroidRuntime( 2652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class TextArea
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at com.soft2rent.unicarmobile.OrigineFragment.onCreateView(OrigineFragment.java:18)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.TextArea
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2652):    ... 35 more`

thanks for reading

Comment: Post logcat stacktrace

Comment: I'm editing right now !

Comment: Shouldn't you be using EditText or TextView instead of TextArea? Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666744/android-how-to-textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
TextArea
```

With

```
TextView
```